# I weight 400 lbs and wondering if it is necessary to buy a second seat

Tags: air-travel, air-canada

I weigh 400 pounds and wonder if it is necessary to buy a second seat on Air Canada.  The seats are about 17.83 inches.

Comment: I don't know their specific rules but you certainly should buy two seats on any airline.